# Trouble getting product URLs

Tags: url

After looking at various methods, the following code is almost getting what I want:

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
 $site_url = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
 $product_url = '';
 $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
 if (sizeof($cats)) {
     $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load((int) $cats[0]);
     $product_url = $site_url.$product->getUrlPath($category);
 }
```

This returns: http://magento.dev/men/shirts/french-cuff-cotton-twill-oxford-570.html.

However this produces a 404.

570 is not the ID that corresponds to this product so I'm wondering where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  `$product_url = $site_url.$product->getUrlPath($category);` those.

You use below **code**

> ```
>  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
>  $product_url = '';
>  $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
>  if (sizeof($cats)) {
>      $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load((int) $cats[0]);
>    if($category->getId()){
>     $product->setCategory($category);
>    }
>  }
> $product_url = $product->getProductUrl();
> ```

### Or via ProductCollection with addUrlRewrite() function:

> ```
> $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
>  $product_url = $product->getProductUrl();
>  $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
>
>  if (sizeof($cats)) {
>    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
>    $collection->addIdFilter($product->getId());
>    if($collection->getSize() >= 1):
>       /* Add addUrlRewrite for add category url with product */
>        $collection->addUrlRewrite((int)$cats[0]);
>        $ProductWithCategory = $collection->getFirstItem();
>        $product_url = $ProductWithCategory->getProductUrl();
>    endif;  
>  }
> ```

Comment: Thanks Amit.  The first recommendation worked and produced the url:
http://magento.dev/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/402/s/french-cuff-cotton-twill-oxford/

The second solution didn't seem to do what was expected.  It produced the URL:
http://magento.dev/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/402/

This seems less "url-rewritten" than the first one.

It seems insane but I'm now seriously considering sticking with my original method but doing a REGEX replace on the ID to produce the correct URL.  Only by doing this horrible hack will I get the URL that the front-end uses.

Comment: Please do indexing from shell check and check the  result

Comment: Hi Amit, I've successfully run "php indexer.php --reindex" and "php indexer.php --reindex all".  This has no impact on the results I'm getting.